# FLENS communication with SQL Server 2008 having visual Studio 2008 c++ as bridge

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, lapack

Is there a way to sommunicate a table in SQL Server with Visual Studio 2008 with a c++ project and then use FLENS library?.

Something like:

> SQL SERVER 2008 -->  Visual Studio
>   2008 (c++) --> FLENS

So storing a table in a matrix in c++ and use FLENS to compute something?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea about the SQL server side of things, but (to the best of my knowledge) there is no Windows/Visual Studio port of FLENS. So I don't see how you could use that library for the linear algebra side of things, even if the rest of whatever it is you have in mind was technically feasible.

Comment: So, is there a way to use c++ library in visual studio? add it in some way¡?

Comment: If you can get FLENS to build with Visual Studio, then of course.